# join with sum and group by

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

I have two tables. They're in a 1:N relationship.

Tasks - Id
     - Name

Report - Id
       - Time
       - TaskId -FK

I'd like to create a query which will sum the report time by a task.

I tried this,but its not working

```
SELECT NAME,SUM (TIME) FROM TASKS LEFT JOIN REPORT ON TASKS.ID = REPORT.TASKID                         
                GROUP BY TASKS.NAME
```

Its Oracle and with this query the time column is null in the result.

Comment: What RDBMS? What is the datatype of `time`? If SQL Server and `time` presumably you are getting the error "Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  NAME, 
  SUM( ISNULL(TIME, 0) ) SumOfTime /* Time could be NULL! */
FROM
  TASKS 
  LEFT JOIN REPORT ON TASKS.ID = REPORT.TASKID                         
GROUP BY
  TASKS.NAME
```

Comment: Aren't group functions ignoring nulls, rather than returning null? What am I missing?

Comment: @boisvert it might be clearer if it was just `isnull(sum(time), 0)`. But, I doubt there would be a noticeable difference in performance.